# host header attack vulnerability

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

In my virtual host file, i have allow all the host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example"
ServerName example.dev
ServerAlias www.example.dev
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/example">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example"
ServerName example.dev
ServerAlias www.example.dev
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/example">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and when i hit the url www.example.dev in the burp software request would shown like below
[image]

> after changing the host name

[image]

> its show the response

[image]

I want if someone try to change the name of the host then it would be redirect to error message page

Comment: I don't understand why you need this? The webserver will read the host and check if it's one of the virtual hosts it knows how to server and if not will respond with the default host. You could make the default host to the be 404 page if you want.

Comment: i need this because while audit, security  guy give me this vulnerability to solve this other wise there is a security issue

Comment: can you please tell me how can i solve this if anyone change the host in between the request then it should redirect to error page

Comment: You have two vhosts for the same hostnames and the same document roots, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just don't trust the `HTTP_HOST` header, that should be enough. The only vulnerability is when you trust the `HTTP_HOST` and people forge it to create malicious links (etc) in your page which may seem more trustworthy.

Comment: All you need to do to make all non-configured hostnames to go get an error message is to create a catch-all vhost (put it last an with no ServerName) and point it to the error message. The first vhost (localhost) doesn't really make any sense either.

Comment: how i know the other vhosts? The security guy add any host name while testing how can i prevent this

Comment: When the server gets a request, it checks all virtual hosts for a match on the requests Hostname and the configured ServerName and ServerAlias. If it finds a match, it will use that. So, if you create a virtual host _without_ a servername or serveralias, it will catch any request. If you put that last, then all request, with a hostname that isnt' specifically configured on the server, will use that one.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: i am getting your point but i am not mention evil.com in my vhost then why it use that request

Comment: Not getting this line "If you put that last, then all request, with a hostname that isnt' specifically configured on the server, will use that one"

Comment: If I put `evil.com` in my hosts file and point it to your servers ip and enter `evil.com` in my browser, the request will go to your server with the hostname `evil.com`, regardless if you have configured it or not. Your configuration determines how the server will handle that request, though. Here's an in-depth article about how Apache handles and matches requests: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html

Comment: i read that should i need to add an another virtual host with default servername?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly my problem, recommended solution is change the HTTP_HOST to SERVER_NAME, which not solving the issue yet.